# Problem with createSlice and redux when i try to do login in mobil browser

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-toolkit

I have a problem when I try to do login in my web app but only in mobile browsers. When I did login in my web app my api "login" works fine but then my app try send me to my dashboard. Here is the problem, I have another api that is called "Me", this api give me the information about the user just logged, but in mobil browsers my api "Me" is giving an error 401 because redux slice becomes to null.

I don't understand why my redux state is null after login in mobile browsers.

This is my code to createSlice:

```js
export const authSlice = createSlice({
  name: "auth",
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    reset: (state) => initialState
  },
  extraReducers:(builder) => {
    builder.addCase(LoginUser.pending, (state) => {
      state.isLoading = true
    });
    builder.addCase(LoginUser.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
      state.isLoading = true;
      state.isSuccess = true;
      state.user = action.payload;
    });
    builder.addCase(LoginUser.rejected, (state, action) => {
      state.isLoading = false;
      state.isError = true;
      state.message = action.payload
    })
    // Get UserLogin
    builder.addCase(getMe.pending, (state /*action*/) => {
      state.isLoading = true;
      //state.user = action.payload;
    });
    builder.addCase(getMe.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
      state.isLoading = true;
      state.isSuccess = true;
      state.user = action.payload;
    });
    builder.addCase(getMe.rejected, (state, action) => {
      state.isLoading = false;
      state.isError = true;
      state.message = action.payload
    })
  }
});

export const { reset } = authSlice.actions;

export default authSlice.reducer;
```

I don't understand why this happens in mobile browsers, but this issue doesn't exist on desktop

this is an example of my web app working on mobile browsers, first my app made a request to my api https://api-cool/login after that if everything is correct then show my dashboard, but when the user is on dashboard my app try to make a request to my api https://api-cool/Me and here is the problem, because the data that I got from api login is null, this just happend in some devices

[image]

this is the redux console but i don't understand why my redux state is null after login in some devices

[image]

My first step in redux is make login, so I got this response:

[image]

After login redux make two reset:
[image]

And then I make a request to my api "/Me" but in the middle of login and getMe in my dashboard my redux becomes null but just in the info that I got from my login.

[image]

This is my login code:

```
export const LoginUser = createAsyncThunk("user/LoginUser", async(user, thunkAPI) => {
    try {
        const response = await axios.post('https://app-cool/login', {
            email: user.email,
            password: user.password
        })
        
        for (const key in response.data) {
            if (response.data.hasOwnProperty.call(response.data, key)) {                
                const element = DOMPurify.sanitize(response.data[key]);
                response.data[key] = element;
                
            }
        }

        return response.data;
    } catch (error) {
        if(error.response){
            const message = error.response.data.msg
            return thunkAPI.rejectWithValue(message);
        }
    }
})
```

and this is my getMe code:

```
export const getMe = createAsyncThunk("user/getMe", async(_, thunkAPLI) => {
    try {
        const response = await axios.get('https://app-cool/Me')
        const data = response.data
        for (const key in data) {
            if (data.hasOwnProperty.call(data, key)) {
                if(key !== 'empresa'){
                    const element = DOMPurify.sanitize(data[key]);
                    data[key] = element;
                }                
            }
        }
        return(response.data);
})
```

In my Login view I have this dispatch for the api "/login":

```
    const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
    const [password, setPassword] = useState("");
    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    const navigate = useNavigate();
    const { user, isError, isSuccess, isLoading, message } = useSelector(
        (state) => state.auth
        );

    useEffect(() => {
        if(user || isSuccess){
            navigate("/dashboard")
        }
        dispatch(reset());
    }, [user, isSuccess, dispatch, navigate])
    
    const Auth = (e) =>{
        e.preventDefault();
        dispatch(LoginUser({email, password}));
    }
```

And my dashboard have this dispatch for my api "getMe":

```
    const { user } = useSelector((state) => state.auth);
    const [votaciones, setVotaciones] = useState([]);
    let votaciones_validas = [];

    useEffect(() => {
        if(user && user.empresa){
            setVotaciones(user.empresa.votacions);
        }
    }, [user]);
```

Comment: Which state is being nullified, can you be more specific? Can you [edit] to provide better details and exact reproduction steps, including any debugging steps you  have already taken?

Comment: @DrewReese I just add mor info about my question, I'm a noob in this topic, I don't know if there exist a debug console for mobile browsers

Comment: It's still unclear if you are saying the *entire* redux state becomes null, only some sub-state becomes null, or that you are just getting some null data in a specific action. Knowing it's a specific dispatched action that starts it, presumably that `"user/getMe"` action, is a good place to start. Can you [edit] to include the `user` state slice and actions, and any relevant code they call, so we can see what it may be doing?

Comment: @DrewReese Sorry for not being clear. I'm using Redux in my login, and the problem only exists on some mobile devices. I don't understand why, but my login works fine and I can recover user data, such as their name and last name. However, something happens when my app sends me to the dashboard because my API endpoint "/Me" needs the information that I received during login. Unfortunately, Redux becomes null and the user data is lost. I just added my code of login and getMe

Comment: Can you also include where and how these `LoginUser` and `getMe` actions are dispatched?

Comment: @DrewReese yes sure, I just add my dispatch that I have in my frontend